# Override magento 2 block ../module_sales/block/adminhtml/totals.php

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override magento block but everytime main block from vendor is executed. No errors are shown.

Magento block:

```
vendor/magento/module_sales/block/adminhtml/totals.php
```

Created block in custom module:

```
[vendor]/[module]/block/adminhtml/totals.php
```

Modified di.xml file in:

```
[vendor]/[module]/etc/di.xml
```

Preference in di.xml file:

```
...
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" 
type="Iways\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" />
...
```

Content of block in custom module:

```
namespace Iways\Sales\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals as DefaultTotals;

class Totals extends DefaultTotals
{
...
```

I have tried to check if file is executed with xdebug but it isnt.

Comment: I don't know if you have pasted this path `[vendor]/[module]/block/adminhtml/totals.php` as is or not, but it should have the initial letter as a capital letter: `[vendor]/[module]/Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you override a block, you also want to add a `sequence` in your `module.xml`. You have to make sure the module of the block you want to override is being loaded before your module is being loaded. See [Component load order](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html). Add the module `Magento_Sales` to your `sequence`.

If that doesn't work:

- Are you sure your module is registered by Magento, can you find your module in `app/etc/config.php'?
- Are you sure there's no other module which overrides that block already?

Comment: Module is loaded and already working correctly, no there is no other module that overrides that block. I am already overriding another block and template with that module and it's working properly. Maybe the problem is because template that is connected to that block which I am trying to override is inside admin panel -> sales -> orders.

Comment: You just said there's no other module that overrides that block in this comment, but in your own answer you said there is a module that overrides your block. You've got two answers on your question which say the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The block that I was trying to extend has already been extended by another block in:

```
module_sales/block/adminhtml/order/totals.php
```

So in general, all I needed to do is to extend that block mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this solution for Magento v-2.3.5

Override this class \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals

app/code/Taktheer/ExtendCoupanTotals/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" type="Taktheer\ExtendCoupanTotals\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Taktheer/ExtendCoupanTotals/Rewrite/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Totals.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Unyscape Infocom Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


   declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Taktheer\ExtendCoupanTotals\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals
{
      /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        
        $order = $this->getSource();
        
        if ($order->getCouponCode()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $order->getCouponCode());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'value' => $order->getDiscountAmount(),
                'base_value' => $order->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
       

     ]
        );
        return $this;
    }

}
```

======================== Happy Coding =============================